# Insert data inside a migration

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

`Model1` used to have a `belongs_to` relationship to `Model2` but now I need to change it for a `has_many` relationship.

Therefore I'm creating a migration with an `model1s_model2s` table. In the migration I'm trying to populate this table (I could do it as a seed, but in this case I think it makes sense that it's inside the migration) with something like this:

```
Model1
|> MyRepo.all()
|> Enum.each(fn x ->
  MyRepo.insert!(%Model1Model2{model1_id: x.id, model2_id: x.model2_id})
end)
```

And I get this error:

```
** (ArgumentError) argument error
    (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:prometheus_histogram_table, {:default, :ecto_db_query_duration_microseconds, [:ok], 1})
(...)
```

I've isolated the error, and it happens in the `MyRepo.all` line. Any command with data query like this one fails. but I can do, for example, `MyRepo.config` without raising errors.

What does that mean? How can I solve it?

Comment: Try adding `Application.ensure_all_started(:my_app)` at the start of the function, replacing `:my_app` with your app's name.

Comment: @Dogbert
I've tried adding that, and I get:

    `[info] Application my_app exited: MyApp.Application.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: MyApp.Repo
    ** (EXIT) already started: #PID<0.293.0>`

Then a few messages like:
`[info] Application xxx exited: :stopped`

And then the migration fails with the same message as before